# How should off-topic discussion and answer on an otherwise on-topic question be handled?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I would like to ask for advice about how a question like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020841/how-to-get-started-with-visual-basic-for-applications) should be handled.

1. The question asked is clearly on topic for SO.
2. The rationale for asking the question is less on topic for SO.
3. Many answers address the question in a perfectly on topic way.
4. However, the most upvoted answer, and the one I personnally think is the most helpful one (given the rationale), would be a better fit for programmers.stackexchange rather than SO.

How can we handle such a case? Moving it to programmers.stackexchange would be awkward because of points (1) and (3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it matter?

It was asked here, leave it here. There is overlapping and grey areas between two different websites, no need to think too much about what to do in these cases, just leave the question on the website it was asked.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily matter - just thought I would ask. :)